# Region of interest - Object detection with SparseOpticalFlow

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, boundary, opticalflow

I am using the [SparseOpticalFlow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) in python. With YOLOv3 I've extracted the boundary boxes of the object I need.

Now I would love to give those boundaries to the SOF algorithm to track only what I want to track.

I've found that there's "[goodfeaturestotrack](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#goodfeaturestotrack)" function that finds the corners for the tracking. This function needs a "mask" param where it said: "mask – Optional region of interest. If the image is not empty (it needs to have the type CV_8UC1 and the same size as image ), it specifies the region in which the corners are detected."

```
prev = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)
```

This "mask" is what I am looking for.

My question is: what are the parameter to create the mask? I mean, it needs width, height, x, y or what else? Anyone can help?

The boundaries boxes param given from the YOLOv3 detector are: floating x, y, width, height. Where x and y start from the top left corner.

**EDIT:**
That's what I've tried to do.

```
# Initialize the mask with all black pixels
mask = np.zeros_like(first_frame)
# Get the coordinates and dimensions of the detect_box
x = 82
y = 69
w = 35
h = 55
# Set the selected rectangle within the mask to white
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255
prev = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_gray, mask = mask, **feature_params)
```

But i get this error...:

```
PS C:\Users\YodhResearch\Desktop\GIULIO FERRARI FOLDER\Giulio _ CSV\Py Script\sparse python> python .\sparseopt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sparseopt.py", line 32, in <module>
    prev = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_gray, mask = mask, **feature_params)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\featureselect.cpp:365: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _mask.empty() || (_mask.type() == CV_8UC1 && _mask.sameSize(_image)) in 
function 'cv::goodFeaturesToTrack'
```

**EDIT2:**

**Solution:**

```
width  = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float
height = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float
print("w = %f" % width)
print("h = %f" % height)
# Initialize the mask with all black pixels
mask = [[0]*int(width)]*int(height)
mask = np.asarray(mask)
mask = mask.astype(np.uint8) 

print( np.shape(mask) )
# Get the coordinates and dimensions of the detect_box
x = 82
y = 69
w = 35
h = 55
# Set the selected rectangle within the mask to white
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255

prev = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(prev_gray, mask = mask, **feature_params)
# Creates an image filled with zero intensities with the same dimensions as the frame - for later drawing purposes
mask = np.zeros_like(first_frame)
```

Comment: `np.zeros_like ` will create a float matrix with zeros. From your error message it shows that your mask should be of type CV_8UC1 (unsigned 8-bit type with single channel). You can convert any numpy matrix type by using `.astype()`. Here you need to add the line - mask = mask.astype(np.uint8) before calling goodFeaturesToTrack.

Comment: Could you add your input image?

Comment: mask is an image of same size as your input image and 0 everywhere where you dont want to process, non-zero everywhere you want to process. So draw your detected boxes filled in white color to a black image and be happy.

Comment: Thanks you SriRaghu for the tip and thanks you Micka for your explanation.
I've found the way and I'll insert in the question.

Thanks again, have a nice day.